# Android: Getting started with the camera and picture uploading / networking

Tags: android, file-upload, frameworks, camera

I am looking for a fast way to get started with an application that can access the camera, quickly take a snapshot and upload it to an internet site.

Since I am looking for RIA Development, I guess I would require a framework (ideally as lightweight as possible).

The best answers for me and most readers, would be one with a code example or framework which  is easy to get into and build upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/)

> PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native
> applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app
> stores. PhoneGap leverages web technologies developers already know
> best... HTML and JavaScript

According to a recent podcast I listened to taking a picture was like one line of code.

Comment: Seems to be a great project. I will try it out.